# Create a PDF with PHPWord from template

Tags: php, phpword

I am trying to load a template, and then save it as a PDF file. I have found multiple ways to do this online, but all of them seems to remove the styling of the word file (which obviously shouldn't happen)

Right now I'm doing this:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\TblWidth;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory;

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('templates/overeenkomst-actie.docx');
$templateProcessor->setImageValue('adviseur_handtekening', array('path' => 'images/handtekeningen/' . $_POST['adviseur'] . '.png', 'width' => 300, 'height' => 100, 'ratio' => false));


$location = $file_location . $time.'-overeenkomst-actie.docx';

$templateProcessor->saveAs($location);

$phpWord = IOFactory::load($location);
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');
```

But as stated before, this does successfully make a pdf, although all the stying is removed.

Comment: The solution for us was not using phpword at all, we made a html template, and converted that to PDF